# Sailsjs generates empty html file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sails.js

I created a new sails project. Everything was working fine suddenly it started generating empty html file. I reverted the changes I made previously but it still continued to generated empty html file. I recreated a new project and after some file changes when I just rearranged some html it started generating empty html again. Below is the file. I have layout.ejs loading from linker assets which worked and homepage.ejs which has html code. I use sails for other projects and did not come across this problem. Any help is appreciated.

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Generating an empty HTML file...where?

Comment: that is the file i get when i try to access localhost:1337. grunt says   
`Running "jst:dev" (jst) task
verbose: Grunt :: >> Destination not written because compiled files were empty`
. but am not able to find the cause. all the paths in the grunt file look fine

Comment: Does your **layout.ejs** have `<%-body%>` in it?

Comment: aah thanks. the layout.ejs file was empty. thanks a lot scott